# DataGridView Image for Button Column

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to add a clickable image/button to a datagridview button column.

The image/button will be an icon for play or stop. If the user clicks the play button a service on the system is started, if the user clicks the stop button a service is stopped.

I already have written functions for starting and stopping the service. What I'm having difficulty with is getting the button/image to show up in the datagrid and making it clickable.

Here's what I have for code:

```
this.dgrdServices.RowPrePaint +=new DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventHandler(dgv_RowPrePaint);
this.dgrdServices.Rows.Add();
this.dgrdServices.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = Image.FromFile(@"C:\users\brad\desktop\green-dot.gif"); 
this.dgrdServices.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = "MyServer";
this.dgrdServices.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = "MyService";
this.dgrdServices.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = "Started";
this.dgrdServices.Rows[0].Cells[4].Value = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
this.dgrdServices.Rows[0].Cells[5].Value = "Uninstall";
```

I can't work out if it would be better to use a button which is an image or an just an image that's clickable. I also can't get a button to show up correctly.

Thanks
Brad

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/DGV_ImageButtonCell.aspx

Comment: So, when you say it is not showing up correctly, is it just not showing up at all? Is it showing, but there is something wrong with the display?

Comment: I've tried various bits of code from examples I can find. I either end up with an unlabeled grey button, or a grey button which says windows.system.bitmap on it. Also I can't work out when the button is pressed to call my function which starts/stops the service.

Comment: Adding the image as a resource to the project may help. Are you actually declare the column as a dgv button column? You're not showing that in your code anywhere.Also from experience, if you have a 1000+ rows the images are going to make the DGV loading slow to a crawl

Comment: @MethodMan - I've seen that example. I couldn't work out how to get it working and it seems to be creating a new class based on an existing class. This seems overly complex. Surely there must be a more straightforward way to do this?

Comment: @michael - I added a datatview grid control to my winforms application then in the properties created a column with a column type of DataGridViewButtonColumn. As far as worrying about 1000+ rows - that's not a worry. At most the datagrid might have 10 rows - and that's an extreme.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Show Image On Button**

You can add a [`DataGridViewButtonColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8), then handle [`CellPainting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) event of the grid and check if the event is raised for your button column, then draw an image on it. At the end of event, don't forget to set `e.Handled = true;`.

In the below code I suppose you have an image resource like `someImage`:

```
private void grid_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0)
        return;

    //I supposed your button column is at index 0
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);

        var w = Properties.Resources.SomeImage.Width;
        var h = Properties.Resources.SomeImage.Height;
        var x = e.CellBounds.Left + (e.CellBounds.Width - w) / 2;
        var y = e.CellBounds.Top + (e.CellBounds.Height - h) / 2;

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(someImage, new Rectangle(x, y, w, h));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

**Show Image Without Button**

To show a single image on all rows including new row, you can set the `Image` property of [`DataGridViewImageColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8). This way the image will be shown in that column on for all rows:

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewImageColumn(){
    Image = someImage, Name = "someName", HeaderText = "Some Text"
});
```

Also if you may want to have different images for cells, you can set the formatted value of `DataGridViewImageColumn` in [`CellFormatting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellFormatting?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) event:

```
void grid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0)
        return;

    //I supposed the image column is at index 1
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
        e.Value = someImage;
}
```

You also can set `Image` property of `DataGridViewImageColumn` to an image, but the image will not show on new row.

**Handle Click**

To handle Click on image/button you can handle [`CellClick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellClick?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) or [`CellContentClick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellContentClick?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) event:

```
void grid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0)
        return;

    //I suposed you want to handle the event for column at index 1
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
        MessageBox.Show("Clicked!");
}
```

If you handled `CellContentClick` you should exactly click on image when you are using image column.

**Screenshot**

Here is the result. First column is a button column showing an image and second column is a normal image column set to show a single image:

[image]

> **Important Note**
>
> In above examples I assume you have an image in `someImage` member
>   variable:
>
> ```
> Image someImage = Properties.Resources.SomeImage
> ```
>
> Make sure you dispose `someImage` on disposal of the form and avoid using `Properties.Resources.SomeImage` directly everywhere you need.

Comment: I got this working but a couple comments - now I see a button with an image on top of it. What I really want to see is only the image. The image needs to be clickable though.

Comment: It is a button column which shows an image which you were looking for *I'm trying to add a clickable image/button to a datagridview button column.*

Comment: If you only want an image, you can simply use a `DataGridViewImageColumn`.

Comment: Also to handle click on button, it's enough to handle `CellContentClick` of grid.

Comment: Getting this error trying to implement an image. Error 1 Property or indexer 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs.Value' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only 
and e.Value has a red squiggle underneath it.

Comment: @Brad Probably you mistakenly copied the code of `CellFormating` event to `CellPainting`. Carefully follow the answer, the screenshot has taken from execution of codes. And let me know the result :)