# DataGridView image column click event

Tags: c#, datagridview, onclick

in DataGridView i customized a column to be image and text
i just want in mouse click event to know if user clicked on image or in the cell it self or text

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Feel free to share some of your code.  It will help us help you.

Comment: Alternative to your solution, [this post about images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36253883/3773066) in an image or button column explains well how you use the `CellClick` or `CellContentClick` events to determine this.

Answer (score 0):

i got it  using PointToClient() method

```
Point point = this.dataGridView1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
```