# How to access new resource(Image) to set as a background

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, visual-studio-2017, embedded-resource

I want to set an image as a background to my button in datagridview. So I follow the following answer [DataGridView Image for Button Column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36253883/418343). I have added my image to the resources like this :

[image]

My problem is I can't access the image in the resources.

```
Properties.Resources. //Here the intellisense doesn't give me the name of my resource.
```

How to access my resource?

Comment: directly resource name `StatementPrint.printer`

Comment: You have added the image to local resource of the form. Add it to project resource file. Also keep in mind, local resource of form doesn't need code generation, so instead of `Publlic` which you have chosen for `Access Modifier` in resource designer, choose `no code Generation`. But for the project Resource file let it be `internal` (which is by default.)

Comment: @RezaAghaei thanks a lot, this was the problem, because i use it as local resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add an image to your project resource file**

1. Go to Solution Explorer → Project node → Properties folder → Resources.Resx
2. Open Resources.Resx in design view by double click on the file.
3. Then it's enough to drag an image from windows explorer and drop it into the designer. The image will be added to the `Resources.Resx`.
4. As another option, you can click on `Add Resource` dropdown and choose `Add Existing File...` from menu.

   [image]

For example if you have added `MyImage.png` to resource file the you can access it in code this way:

```
this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.MyImage;
```

**Just in case your project doesn't have such `Resources.Resx` file**

1. Right click on Project → Choose *Properties*
2. In project properties window, choose *Resources* (left side, bottom of the list).
3. At the center, you will see a link *This project does not contain a default resources file. Click here to create one.* Click on the link and it will create a `Resources.Resx` file under `Properties` folder for your project.

**Select Resource Dialog for Image properties**

You can also add the image to project resource file from *Select Resource* dialog. To do so, open your `Form` in design view:

1. Open Properties window → BackgroundImage property → Click on `...` button in front of the property in property grid.
2. In the Select Resource dialog, make `Properties\Resources.Resx` has been selected in combobox.
3. Click on `Import` button and choose an image and press OK.

The designer will add the image to resource file and set it as `BackgroudImage` property of the form.