# How to add picturebox controls to datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-core, datagridview

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    dataGrid = new DataGridView();
    dataGrid.DataSource = this._lstWorklet;
    dataGrid.DataBindingComplete += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventHandler(dataGrid_DataBindingComplete);
}

private void dataGrid_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox _btnView = new PictureBox();
    _btnView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(24, 24);
    _btnView.BackgroundImage = ProcessingDataModel._viewImg;
    _btnView.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Center;
    _btnView.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
    _btnView.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnViewRecording_click);
    System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip _toolTipView = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
    _toolTipView.SetToolTip(_btnView, "View Recording");


    PictureBox _btnDelete = new PictureBox();
    _btnDelete.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(24, 24);
    _btnDelete.BackgroundImage = ProcessingDataModel._deleteImg;
    _btnDelete.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Center;
    _btnDelete.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
    _btnDelete.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnDeleteRecording_click);
    System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip _toolTipDelete = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
    _toolTipDelete.SetToolTip(_btnDelete, "Delete Recording");

    dataGrid.Columns[3].Name = "Action";
    dataGrid.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Action";
    dataGrid.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

    for (int i = 0; i <= dataGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
       dataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[3].Controls.Add(_btnView);
       dataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[3].Controls.Add(_btnDelete);
    }
}
```

I am getting error in for loop on (dataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[3].Controls.Add(_btnView)) like **'DataGridViewCell' does not contain a definition for 'Controls' and no accessible extension method 'Controls' accepting a first argument of type 'DataGridViewCell' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**
So please help me about adding the Picturebox to the column in datagridview for windows application.

[image]

Comment: You could add a pb to the DGV.Controls collection but it wouldn't integrate with the rows&cols. - You can create a custom Cell type, but that is rather complex. Or maybe it is enough to simply use a ImageColumn..?

Comment: But my issue is I want to add two image buttons in a single column and want to handle its click event

Comment: So now it is no longer a PictureBox but a Button with an image? So your question title is wrong. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253732/datagridview-image-for-button-column)

Comment: ..or [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27146/DataGridView-Image-Button-Cell)

Comment: But this are not working in my case.

Comment: _Not working_ is not a helpful problem description! - What happens? Nothing? Errors? (Which?) Crashes? Wrong results? (Which?)

Comment: It shows an Image but the problem is the value of that image is a text value which is date time value from the previous cell. So I can not identify about which image is been clicked.

Comment: Huh? Which of the propsed solutions did you try? Where is the code? The code you show can't work as Cells are not Controls and therefore don't have a controls collection.